# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Class not found during runtime.

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on eclipse, and I have the need to use external library's. For example Jsoup and JXL.

Now what I have done so far is: First created a "lib" folder in my project folder. Afterwards in eclipse, click on project properties, Libraries tab, add external jar and added the jar in the lib folder.

So this solve my compilation issue. Now, when I run the program (I go to project/bin and in the console execute: java ProgramName ; I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

Now to testing, I added the Jar file to the folder where Main.java is and Now, I have been able to run the program doing the following:

```
javac -classpath ./path/to/jar Main.java
java -classpath ./path/to/jar:. Main
```

And this works.

So the first thing that comes to mind is that I have to tell java where to find the respective libraries. If this is correct? How do I do it?

```
java -cp ???(dont know what to put here)
```

But moreover. I have another issue. I am writing this program in a computer, but I am going to use it in other which probably don't have those libraries. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: You are already asked the similar question. Did you try to put library to classpath of app server, as I mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16149435/1430055 ?

Comment: And how shall you invoke methods on other library classes which are not present in the other computer, without copying the jar files to other computer?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use something like the following:

`java -cp myjar.jar;lib/*.jar com.foo.bar.MyClass`

This adds not only my jar to the classpath but those in the `lib` directory as well.

If you want to run your jar on another computer, you *will* need those jars as well, you cant just have your jar. Why not just also package your lib directory along with it?

Comment: This might be very silly, but I am having trouble using the -cp command. I used your command. But it threw me an error. It says permission denied

Answer (score 0):

To get your program to run you have two paths to worry about

1. The path to the jar files that are your applications dependencies (like jsoup.jar) (lets call this lib)
2. The path to the directory containing the classes of your app (lets call this classes)

The general form of the command line you need is:

```
java -cp lib/jsoup.jar:classes Main
```

If you have more libs

```
java -cp lib/jsoup.jar:lib/jxl.jar:classes Main
```

A general note on packaging your app for release to other computers.  You might want to consider making a jar of your own app, probably best done using http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

Another option is to produce a "one jar", which makes one large jar, bundling in all the classes you need from your libs and all the classes in your app.  You can then make the jar executable for a nice out of the box solution.  Have a look at http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/ and https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/

Comment: First thing I need to do is to be able to run it. Which I am having trouble using the java -cp

Comment: I am using: java -cp ../lib/jxl-2.6.jar:classes Main     but it says Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Comment: What directory is Main.class in?

Comment: If we are on the root of the project folder, we have /bin /lib /src  and Main.class is in /bin. I am executing this command inside /bin

Comment: ok.  "classes" is meant to be the directory in which Main resides.  So you need java -cp ../lib/jxl-2.6.jar:. Main if you are running from bin.  If you are in the root then java -cp lib/jxl-2.6.jar:bin Main

Answer (score 0):

if you have this structure:

```
project folder
... code
... libs
```

then from the code folder:

```
javac -cp .;../libs/*.jar yourmainclass.java
java -cp  .;../libs/*.jar yourmainclass
```

When you need to compile and run this project, take all the folder and do the same in other machine.

Comment: Ok I am in the code folder, and executed what you wrote but I am getting an error. Very Strange. Want to post it here?

Comment: This is what I get:
alessandro@ALC:~/Java/Trabajo/src$ javac -cp .;../lib/*.jar Main.java 

javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
bash: ../lib/jxl-2.6.jar: Permission denied